# ModuleNotFoundError -> Imported module cannot import another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Working directory is shaped like:

```
* main_script.py

/ module_to_import

    * __init__.py

    * script_1.py

    * script_2.py
```

In main_script.py we have

```
from module_to_import import script_1

script_1.call_something()
```

In script_1.py we have

```
import script_2

def call_something():
    something = script_2.get_something()
    something = something + 1
    return something
```

When main_script.py is run
This returns a

> > ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'script_2'

I understand this could be provisionally resolved by directly importing script_2 into main_script.

Is there a way to resolve this so that script_1 can reliably import script_2 even when main_script has not imported script_2 itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your package is structured as a subpackage, in script_1.py you can use either absolute import

```
import module_to_import.script_2 as script_2
```

or relative one:

```
from . import script_2
```

You can find the documentation about it here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references